# Haskell Platform last version

Tags: apt, package-management

I have installed the latest available version of the Haskell platform on Elementary with `apt-get`
But the actual version is pretty old:

```
> sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
haskell-platform is already the newest version (2014.2.0.0.debian2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can i install the newest version? https://www.haskell.org/platform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PPA for GHC and Cabal, you should check if it is what you need:

https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc

You can add this to your system with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hvr/ghc
sudo apt-get update
```

Or you can install the generic Linux version if you need to use a more recent version of the full Haskell Platform. However this does not take advantage of the elementary OS package system.

https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#linux-generic